# How to remove &nbsp; from the end of spans with a given class?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I need to remove the `&nbsp;` after the value of given spans.
The HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="number">0.15&nbsp;</span>
```

The &nbsp; 
is coming from the server (CMS).

Is there any way to remove the &nbsp; by using CSS rules?

Comment: Not with CSS only (at least not really in a nice way).

Comment: Why specifically do you want to remove it? By default, white space characters are collapsed.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst what do you mean with collapsed? A _real_ space at the beginning or the end in a tag has no visual effect, a `&nbsp;` on the other side creates a visual space.

Comment: I want to remove that nbsp as it collapse the alignment. I do not want to use jquery to handle this one. Can not CSS handle this type of cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this value is provided by your CMS, it's posible you can modify the value with php via `str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $yourVar)` before echo it in your span.

If you can't access with this, you can also use jQuery to do this... Just like Muhammad Ali said:

```
var str = $('.number').html();
str = str.replace('&nbsp;', '');
$('.number').html(str);
```

Something like this could work. But with CSS, isn't posible I guess.

Comment: thanks, It can be done with JQuery but i want this to be done by using CSS as there are lot of JS files are there on my page.

Comment: Using ```.number:before { content:'something' }``` is the only posibility you have. I'm afraid that you can't get the content already in your span and modify them via CSS.

Comment: I dont think we can use "content" here because that entire content is coming from backend. We can not hard-code that value(0.15&nbsp;)

Comment: And you have to know CSS wasn't designed to perfork this kind of actions. Prefer Javascript or PHP solution if you can bypass your backend.

Comment: Yes you are right. I too thought the same but I was hoping there would be some way to handle it by CSS. Let me go-ahead with jQuery as Muhammad Ali and Bardyl said. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with only css. Somehow you have to use jquery for this. With Regular Expression you can simply do this.

```
var span = $('span').html();
span = span.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
$('span').html(span);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/76k57/)

**Note:** `&nbsp;` is coming from CMS them you have to use jquery code to replace it when your document loaded fully.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var span = $('span').html();
    span = span.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
    $('span').html(span);
});
```

Comment: As OP said he don't want to use jQuery. If it is not possible with css only then justify it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot possibly remove characters from document content with CSS. That’s not what CSS is for. You can *add* characters to be rendered, with generated content, but not remove.

However, you might be able to undo the *effects* of a character on rendering. Consider the following example:

```
<span class="number">0.15&nbsp;</span>foo
```

The no-break space (`&nbsp;`) has two effects: it causes visible spacing, the same as a normal space character, and it prevents line break between “0.15” and “foo” when the browser formats the text. To prevent the latter effect, you could add a normal space using generated content, but then there will be too much spacing when a line break does not appear. To fix this, set the width of the pseudo-element to zero:

```
.number:after { content: " "; display: inline-block; width: 0; }
```

To remove the spacing effect of the no-break space, you can set a negative right margin. The main problem with this is that the width of a no-break space (and a space) depends on the font. It is on the average about one fourth of an `em`, but it may vary considerably. If you can regard the font as fixed (e.g., you are using `@font-face`), you can use the following code, with just the numeric value tuned as needed:

```
 .number {  display: inline-block; margin-right: -0.25em; }
```

As a side effect, this may also allow a line break between “0.15” and “foo”, since browsers may handle inline blocks in formatting so that they always allow line breaks before and after.

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript/Jquery framework to remove any charackey like this exampe [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JfE39/)

```
var span = $('span').html();
span = span.replace('&nbsp;','');
$('span').html(span);
```

Comment: This only replaces the first instance, and jQuery is certainly not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can not remove `&nbsp;` completely using CSS, the CSS rules below can enforce the behavior of a normal space.

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with JS, or PHP. It depends on what you use. overflow-wrap: break-word or word-break: break-word also break letters and it's not correct for grammar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).