# Text-align:justify only works on indented (complicated) HTML code, not on HTML code without whitespaces

Tags: css, html, text-align, justify

I'm maintaining an online newspaper editor, and I've stumbled on a weird issue, where text doesn't want to be justified with text-align:justify. After a few hours of debugging, I noticed it might have something to do with the output HTML indenting (which sounds realy weird to me).

Obviously the raw HTML output of my editor page isn't indented, but a text field has a basic structure like this:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span>
      <span>
        <span>
          Hello&nbsp;
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span>
      <span>
        <span>
          World.
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Every word is wrapped in 3 spans(rendered by JS/jQuery, for styles, fonts & uniformity between browsers), and I put the `text-align:justify;` in the `<p>` element.

Here's some sample code:
https://jsfiddle.net/tdje0a9L/

As you can see, the text isn't justified.

But now, when i **indent** the exact same HTML code, it becomes justified: 
https://jsfiddle.net/3v7vk24d/

I can't realy do much about the multiple span wrapping, that's just how the editor works.

Now is my question:

- is there any way to render the output HTML indented?

  (to get my text justified)

  or
- is there an other way to get my text justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) entities in you source code - that means that you code really don't have spaces between words.

So for `text-align: justify` it seams to be one word.

Your example will print: `Donec quam felis` as one word

You can look in this question for some more information how you can remove your unwanted entities: [How to remove &nbsp; from the end of spans with a given class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132329/remove-nbsp-from-span-class)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solution works. However, on the `<span>` is `display:inline-block` used, and if I replace the `nbsp;` with regular spaces , all words are being glued together.. I guess I'll just remove the inline-block and hope it doesn't break anything :)